# Convert `String` to `AccountId` in ink! contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, account

I want to write a method which takes a `String` and converts it to an `AccountId`, like this:

```rust
pub fn send(
    &mut self,
    address: String
) -> Result<()> {
    // Some type conversion `address` to `account`
    self.env().transfer(account, value)
}
```

There's no type conversion from `String` to `AccountId` as part of the traits implemented on `AccountId`. How can I do this conversion?

Comment: your question is not clear, what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Adam, you should prefer to take an `AccountId` directly
instead of a `String`.

That said, if you do want to do this here is an option:

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn convert(&mut self, s: ink::prelude::string::String) -> AccountId {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();
    let account = AccountId::try_from(bytes).expect("You should handle this properly.");
    account
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question is: "How to parse `AccountId` from `String` in an ink contract method?"

First, I would reconsider if this is actually needed. Why not make the method parameter to be of type `AccountId`?

In a contract code one is not limited to methods from the `AccountId` trait, but can use other methods implemented by the concrete type being used in the environment. The `AccountId` type is configurable, so one could provide a type with appropriate method for parsing strings. E.g. `sp_runtime::AccountId32` has a [`FromStr` implementation](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/struct.AccountId32.html#impl-FromStr-for-AccountId32).

Comment: Unfortunately `FromStr` is `std` only. Given ink contracts are written in `no_std` environment, we should use an external crate like `hex` to parse the string to `&[u8]`, and then convert it to `AccountId32` by `TryInto`.